# How to calculate the parity bit of the following bit sequence?

Tags: networking, parity, hamming-code

The sequence is:

00111011

How do i calculate the parity bit for the above sequence? This question is from Databases- The complete book by jeffery ullman (**Exercise 13.4.1 a**)

I am not sure what the answer to this question should be.

Is it as simple as :

i)Even Parity : the number of 1s is 5 (odd) so just append a 1 and the answer is : 001110111

ii)Odd Parity: likewise , just append 0: 001110110

OR:

am i on a totally wrong path here? I looked up on the net but could not find anything concrete . Also, the text for the above question in the text book is not clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, your answers are correct. For the given sequence,

**00111011**

Odd Parity is **001110110**, the parity bit is zero so that the total number of 1's in the code is 5, which is an Odd number.

The Even Parity is **001110111**, the parity bit is one so that the total number of 1's in the code is 6, which is an Even number.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use XOR i.e;
00111011

```
0XOR0=0
0XOR0=0
0XOR1=1
1XOR1=0
0XOR1=1
1XOR0=1
1XOR1=0
0XOR1=1
```

, The last bit is the parity bit; 1 for even parity, 0 for odd parity. you should make this bit the LSB of the original number (00111011) thereby becoming (001110111).

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned char CalEvenParity(unsigned char data)
{
unsigned char parity=0;

while(data){
        parity^=(data &1);
        data>>=1;
            }
return (parity);
}
```

Comment: initialize Parity variable with '1'  for odd parity calculation

Answer (score 1):

Alternate implementation of parity:

This involves doing an XOR between the consecutive bits in a particular number in an integer.

The x>>1 left shifts the value by 1 bit and the & 1, gets us the value of the last bit of the number.

Parity of the entire sequence can be visualized as below:- i.e due to the properties of XOR.

1 ^ 0 ^ 1 is same as (1 ^ 0 ) ^ 1 and we extend the same.

```
def parity_val(x):
    parity=0
    while x>>1:
     parity =  (x & 1)^ ((x >>1) & 1)
     x = x>> 1
    return parity
```

Comment: Add more info on why this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution without any loops for a 16 bit sequence, as the given sequence fits the 16 bit number. You will get 1 for an odd number of set bits, and 0 for an even number of set bits.

```
uint8_t parity(uint16_t data) {
    data ^= data >> 8;
    data ^= data >> 4;
    data ^= data >> 2;
    data ^= data >> 1;
    return data & 1;
}
```